# google-api-java-client: samples

Tags: google-api-java-client

A silly question: is there an easy way (zip/jar) to download the samples of google-api-java-client? (vs one by one by browsing the sources)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to become familiar with Mercurial and get your IDE setup to use it.  Once you've got your head around it, then it's a matter of saying to your IDE, "grab all the code at this URL and treat it like a new module/project".  Each of the samples specifies the hg URL to use (for example, http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/GoogleAPIs#Setup_directions)

Pretty much, the sooner you relent and allow yourself to be forced to use hg and maven, the better it will be for you in the future.

You might find [hginit.com](http://hginit.com/) useful on the Mercurial aspect.
The Apache Maven docs suck less than they used to, but you will still be up against it.

cheers,
David.

Comment: I hope you appreciate this answer - I had to go and get 100 reputation just so I could put 2 hyperlinks :-)

Comment: Good answer, although you only need to learn how to check out the code.  Alternatively from the command line from http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/checkout?repo=samples : hg clone https://samples.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/ google-api-java-client-sample

Answer (score 0):

Google Code recently launched a feature (somewhat silently) that allows you to download the contents of a repository as a zip.

You can see it by going to https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/?repo=samples and clicking on the "Download zip" link.

As of right now, the download link for the latest commit is https://samples.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/archive/7a1ee66ffe98b78d54b2bdeca3c95fe440c886d9.zip